# Div overlapping a select stops it from opening

Tags: html, css, select

I recently had a problem with an invisible `div` overlapping a `select` element. Clicking overlapped part prevented the select list from opening so you could pick an option. I'm trying to understand this behavior. This is cross-browser,
 so I'm guessing it's intended. [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/782c8csg/4/).

The divs are absolutely positioned, while the select is static. z-index doesn't apply to static elements, but are absolute elements positioned "above" static ones?

This isn't a Javascript issue, because this isn't the click event. This is a "browser handling the select element being frobbed" issue.

Is there any way to get around this, so clicking on a div passes the click down to the select element?

Comment: in which browser it is not working?

Comment: `#div1, #div2 {pointer-events: none;}` https://jsfiddle.net/0cfkh9tL/

Comment: Try adding following css to the elements you want to click through: "pointer-events: none;"

Comment: If that was an answer, @sol, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pointer-events` property. From MDN:

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse
>   events.

[Full Information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

[Browser support from CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) - Note there is no support below IE11

```css
* {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2" style="position: absolute; border: 1px dashed blue; width: 50px; top:0; left: 60px;">
  <span id="span2">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<select name="foo" id="select1">
    <option value="1">This is my option</option>
</select>

<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; border: 1px dashed red; width: 50px; top:0; left: 10px;">
  <span id="span1">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```